# How to find every table/columns in SQL with a string/number

Tags: sql

I'm Searching for a query to find all possible columns and table names for a specific piece of string/number.

Let's say I have a string/number as `100031-16-FWMD-D20`, is there a query to find all the columns and table names which has the value in my database?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? There are already solutions for most of them here on stackoverflow anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Column name-----

Select * from information_schema.columns where column_ name like '%string%'

Table name----

Select * from information_schema.tables where table_name like '%string%'

Comment: The question is, to find the columns which has the value of `100031-16-FWMD-D20` in their database, **not** listing the column/table names which are matching the given name

Comment: Ok, run a loop on the basis of number of columns and put the following query in every loop condition

Comment: Select * from mytable where col like '%string%'

Comment: Yes, so the answer is different. You may [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54092105/edit) to change the content.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you string up the columns for text datatype from information_schema.columns and after that use the query which is creatd to manually query the search string

```
Step 1:
select 'select '+column_name+' as search_text,'''+table_name+''' as table_name from '+TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME+' union all'
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
where TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo'
  and data_type like '%char%'

Step 2: 
        select * 
          from(<output of Step 1 after removing the last 'union all')x 
         where x.search_text  like '%100031-16-FWMD-D20%'
```